# Order counted and filtered Google Sheets Query Results

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I am working on a Google Sheet intended to aid in the analysis of Marketing-related KPIs. For this, I have created (or rather researched from different sources) my first Query, which looks up different columns from a different sheet based on one column "date" and groups them while counting how many times different values appear.
Now, I would like to also sort this query by the counted values.

The code currently looks like this:

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE(QUERY(
Gruppenname_klaeren!A3:I;"SELECT * WHERE I is not null 
and B >= date'"&TEXT(today()-A2;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
and B <= date '"&TEXT(today();"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
label I 'Kampagne'")); 
"SELECT Col9, count(Col3) WHERE Col9 is not null GROUP BY Col9 label count(Col3) 'Anzahl GKs'")
```

Honestly, the code feels like a mess – but that's the only way I could make it work. Now, I would like to order the results based on the values of count(Col3), but just inserting this in the following way doesn't work:

```
"SELECT Col9, count(Col3) WHERE Col9 is not null GROUP BY Col9 label count(Col3) 'Anzahl GKs' order by count(Col3) desc")
```

If anyone knows why this doesn't work, I'd really appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=SORT(QUERY(UNIQUE(QUERY(
Gruppenname_klaeren!A3:I;"SELECT * WHERE I is not null 
and B >= date'"&TEXT(today()-A2;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
and B <= date '"&TEXT(today();"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
label I 'Kampagne'")); 
"SELECT Col9, count(Col3) WHERE Col9 is not null GROUP BY Col9 label count(Col3) 'Anzahl GKs'");3;0)
```

I have encapsulated your formula by `sort(___________;3;0)`

1 = ASC
0 = DESC

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! I had to change the column by which it sorts from 3 to 2 since I only have 2, but it did the trick. Thanks a bunch!